# Function to determine data size

Tags: c, embedded, programming

I am using eeprom emulator which writes a page of flash of 60 bytes at once. Data to be written to that page is first stored in a 60 byte buffer (array of 60 elements) in ram and then transferred to flash at once.
Now I want to make my own function  above that library which will take address as well as data and store it in  page buffer accordingly. That is, if the data is 16 bit long then it should store it in two consecutive location in page buffer array, If it is 8 bit long then it should store it at single location pointed by address.
My query is how can my function determine size of data, I want to store, just from the data variable

Comment: It can't as far as I can see -- you'll need to provide a parameter that specifies the size.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  This question does not appear to be about electronics design within the scope defined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really an electronics or embedded systems question.

If you use C++, you can make write multiple functions under one name, thanks to overloading:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

void store_data(void *addr, uint8_t data);
void store_data(void *addr, uint16_t data);
void store_data(void *addr, uint32_t data);
void store_data(void *addr, uint64_t data);
```

Each overload knows how large the data is from the type of its argument.

In C, you could have a macro:

```
void store_data_sz(void *addr, size_t size, void *pdata);

/* data argument of macro must be an lvalue */
#define store_data(addr, data) store_data_sz(addr, sizeof (data), &(data))
```

There is also something to be said for just having separate functions for common sizes, and then a general one for variable length:

```
void store_8(void *addr, int data);
void store_16(void *addr, int data);
void store_32(void *addr, unsigned long data);
void store_buf(void *addr, void *buf, size_t size);
```

We can have a macro interface to this, again. Here we have some system dependencies, like the assumption that if something is of size 1, it an 8 bit unit, and so on:

```
#define store_data(addr, data) do {                 \
  switch (sizeof(data)) {                           \
  case 1: store_8(addr, data); break;               \
  case 2: store_16(addr, data); break;              \
  case 4: store_32(addr, data); break;              \
  case 8: store_64(addr, data); break;              \
  default: store_buf(addr, &(data), sizeof (data)); \
  }                                                 \
} while (0)
```

Since `sizeof(data)` is a constant expression (the exception to this being C99 variable-length arrays), we know at compile time that only one of the switch cases is reachable; any decent compiler will throw away the impossible cases.  Check the compiled code disassemble to be sure.

Comment: I think your `store_data` macro only works if `data` in the calling code is declared as an array, and will break if `data` is declared as a pointer.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, that is a mistake; we have to take the address. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

It can't.  A pointer to 8 bits of data is exactly the same as a pointer to 16 bits of data.  You will have to either provide an extra parameter which tells the function how big the data is, or provide two different functions, one for 8 bit and one for 16 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way for you to do it directly, but if you need that sort of functionality, you could write your function to take an extra parameter which specifies the data size and then wrap that in a macro which includes a sizeof().

Something like this:

```
    int my_func (void *data, int size)    {
   // do stuff with *data and use value in size
    }

#define mc_func(thing)    my_func(&thing, sizeof(thing))
```

Then if you do something like:

```
mc_func(my_16bit_variable);
```

you'll end up having your my_func function called with the address of `my_16bit_variable` in `*data` and 2 in `size`.